# Why use 分 in this question?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have come across the following sentence :

> そのダンボールゴミに出す分ですか？

I understand it means something like "Are you throwing out this cardbox?". But what does 分 mean in this context and why is it at that position in the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> そのダンボ－ルはゴミに出す**分**ですか？
>   Is that cardboard box **the part** you are putting out with the rubbish?

分 here means "part". Another example:

> これは亜美ちゃんにあげる分だ。
>   This is the part I am giving to Abi. *or*
>   This is what I am giving to Abi. *or*
>   This is Abi's share.

Comment: But ゴミに出す分がある implies ゴミに出さない分もある, not implies ゴミに出す分が他にもある...

Comment: @Hyperworm Where did you get that from?

Comment: Realized my → notation might have been confusing. Edited. What I mean is that 分 here tells you this box belongs to the "part" (of all things) that is for the rubbish, implying the presence of another "part" that is **not** for rubbish. It doesn't mean that the box is "part" of the rubbish (as in your bold), implying that there is another "part" that is **also** for the rubbish. As I understand it.

Comment: For perhaps clearer wording -- if I apply your bolded translation to the second example, it comes out as "This is **part of the things** I am giving to Abi" -- can you see how that differs (wrongly) from "This is Abi's share"?

Comment: I see what you mean. With the bolded part, all I intended it to mean was "corresponds to", not "equals".

Comment: @Hyperworm　ああ、つまり「ゴミに出す分」というからには、どこかに「ゴミに出さない分」がある、ということで、「アミちゃんにあげる分」というには、どこかに「自分の分」か「アミちゃん以外の人にあげる分」などがあるはず、ということですね。

Comment: Seems Hyperworm has got the idea. Here, 分 means more like "a batch of stuff (gathered for a specific purpose.)" and that puropose is to throw it away.  The contents of this box belong in that batch.  Using the word "part" could only confuse OP and others who might not understand the sentence in question.  There is surely at least another batch for a different purpose.  Otherwise, one could not even use the word 分.