# What does 円分 mean after a number?

Tags: pragmatics

Is 分 a counter after 円 following a number, e.g. 500円分?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [分 in 今回は単行本第三巻予定分から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30054/%e5%88%86-in-%e4%bb%8a%e5%9b%9e%e3%81%af%e5%8d%98%e8%a1%8c%e6%9c%ac%e7%ac%ac%e4%b8%89%e5%b7%bb%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12040/5010

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate. I cannot apply what is answered in the link provided to the case of 円分. It would be nice if someone explained how 分 is applied to 円.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm understanding naruto's link correctly, the 「５００円**分**」 here means "**worth of** 500 yen". From the [linked answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30054/%e5%88%86-in-%e4%bb%8a%e5%9b%9e%e3%81%af%e5%8d%98%e8%a1%8c%e6%9c%ac%e7%ac%ac%e4%b8%89%e5%b7%bb%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89):

> 1日**分**の食料: a day's **worth of** food

To put it in context:

> 会員専用サービス「ピッとGo」をご利用で電子優待券プレゼント！
>   *By using our members-only "beep-and-go" service, you get an electronic complimentary ticket as a present!*
>   免許証情報登録で
>   *By registering your driving license information* 
>   ご利用ごとに、何度でも
>   *Every time you use it, any number of times*
>   ５００円**分**（の優待券）
>   *(a ticket) **worth of** 500 yen*

Comment: A little bit tricky with Yen though, in case of food it goes before 分, but in case of 円 it goes after.

Comment: @user1602 I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Do you mean that ５００円分 comes after 優待券?

Comment: 分 is a suffix to５００円, and a prefix (or attribute) to 食料, this is why I could not apply the "worth" logic to Yen.

Comment: @user1602 How I understand it is that the 分 works the same way in both of them. A bad literal translation: "Food worth of 1 day" (1日分の食料) ↔ A complimentary ticket worth of 500 yen (５００円分の優待券)

Comment: Now I see it, thank you. I understand part, but "worth of something" was not obvious to me :)