# How to interpret 分 in the following passage

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> 報酬**分**は働かせてもらうよ。もちろん追加をもらえりゃあ、その**分**よく働くってもんさ。

The first sentence is ambiguous to me. Is the second sentence actually an explanation of the first sentence here, i.e. "let me work the amount appropriate to the amount that you pay me" and that the first 分 and the second 分 are being used in the same manner here?

There is a later passage with a similarly ambiguous statement:

> 出撃の時はあたしに任せな。報酬**分**はきっちり働くよ。こう見えて、雇い主を満足させる女なのさ。

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Both instances of 分 are essentially the same, it's a noun/suffix meaning "amount that corresponds to ～", "～'s fraction", "～'s worth (of something)".

- 報酬分: (amount of) work that corresponds to my reward; work worth my reward
- その分: (amount of) work that corresponds to 追加 (additional reward); according to the extra payment

This person is basically saying the more she is paid, the more earnestly she will work.

Related:

- [分 in 今回は単行本第三巻予定分から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30054/5010)
- [What does 円分 mean after a number?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47164/5010)

Answer (score -1):

The first 分 is described below.
It is attached after nouns and expresses the idea of equivalence, or correspondence.
Examples:
増加分: An amount equivalent to the increase.
苦労分: An amount equivalent to the the effort.
五日分: An amount equivalent to 5 days.

他の名詞につけて用いる。
㋐それに相当するもの、それに見合うものの意を表す。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/197124/meaning/m1u/分/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/197124/meaning/m1u/%E5%88%86/)

The second 分 is described below. 
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/其の分/#je-44193](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%85%B6%E3%81%AE%E5%88%86/#je-44193)
It is used as an expression "その分" and means "to the same amount", "to the same rate", "to the same proportion".

So the translation becomes:

報酬分は働かせてもらうよ。
You have to work as hard as the amount of your salary
もちろん追加をもらえりゃあ、
of course I will pay you more for extra work
その分よく働くってもんさ。
But in exchange you have to work as hard as I am paying you.

Comment: was this downvoted for the translations at the end, or for the explanation of the word 分??  If for the translations, whoever downvoted, are you unhappy with "less literal" English being too far removed from the original meanings of the words, or is the translation actually faulty in some way??

Comment: ^　ダウンボートしたの私じゃないですけど、「報酬分は働かせてもらうよ。もちろん追加をもらえりゃあ、その分よく働くってもんさ。」の主語（働く人）は、you じゃないです。。

Comment: you mean that it's some unspecified person? Where in English we would use "they/them"?  And is that automatically understood by the sentence structure, or do you need context to be aware of that?

Comment: ^ はっ？エリックさんしっかりしてー　「働かせてもらう」(=働く)・「追加をもらう」・「よく働く」の主語は全部、話者=「あたし」= "I" ですよおー　「追加をもらえりゃあ」= (私があなたから)追加をもらえれば, "If you pay me extra fee"

Comment: doh...  I saw that earlier, and yeah, I totally zoned on that...  -_-!!  エリックしっかりしてー  :( ほんまに。。。

Comment: As @Chocolate mentioned, the one who's doing the work is the one's who is saying these sentences so this mistake makes this answer unreliable.