# Is 分じゃない a specific meaning?

Tags: negation, questions, rhetorical-questions

Character starts crying and says this:

"あれ　なんだこれ。。。"

To which the other character replies this:

"今まで我慢してきた分じゃない?"

My reading of 今まで我慢してきた分 is "the amount you have endured until now". However why is じゃない? used here? It is mean to be じゃないか for "Isn't it"?

Because "It isn't the amount..." Sounds odd

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain you have seen this type of "～じゃない?", which translates to "It's ～, isn't it?"

> ペンじゃない？
> It's a pen, isn't it? / It's a pen, no?

Your understanding of 分 is just right.

- [How to interpret 分 in the following passage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61566/5010)
- [分 in 今回は単行本第三巻予定分から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30054/5010)

Thus, the sentence translates to:

> 今まで我慢してきた分じゃない?
>
> It (corresponds to) the amount you have endured until now, doesn't it?

If I guessed the context correctly, the sentence implies "You have endured enough (without crying) until now, so you can cry now".